# How to set the title of a modal window in Drupal 7

Tags: 7, routes

I am using the following code to create a new page, which is rendered as a modal window by using a link with the ctools modal attributes:

```
$items['mymodule/%ctools_js'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'mymodule_callback',
    'page arguments' => array(1),
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
);
```

Notice that the type is **MENU_CALLBACK**. I would like to set a title to the page, because the full page is accessed by Googe via mymodule/nojs/ctools_js, and it displays no title. I have tried with the following two added first lines of code, but it does not do anything. Also with drupal_set_title in the callback function it didn't work.

```
 $items['mymodule/%ctools_js'] = array(
   'title' => 'some title, please! ',
   'title callback' => 'mymodule_title_callback',
   'page callback' => 'mymodule_callback',
   'page arguments' => array(1),
   'access callback' => TRUE,
   'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
 );
```

I think it is an obvious question, but I don't manage to make it work. I am not sure if this is because of the type (ajax) menu page or whatever other reason.

Comment: what's in this one: mymodule_title_callback?

Comment: With that function (which the documentation says is optional) I tried several things: return a string, do a drupal_set_title,... Everything failed. If the type of the item menu is **MENU_NORMAL_ITEM**, it works perfectly the above code. When I set **MENU_CALLBACK**, it stops working. Every time flushing the cache, even from database and running cron. I will have to assume it is a bug.

Comment: I must add that I have now solved the problem without doing anything. The test site in XAMPP is working exactly as described. The same version of Drupal, but with CTOOLS and other modules installed, in production, is working correctly. All with the title and title callback parameters. I do not understand anything.

Comment: Why do you want to use MENU_CALLBACK over another one?

Comment: I don't want the page to appear in menus or breadcrumbs, as it is a layer, a modal window. The problem is with Google boths or with the browser having the Javascript turned off, it will render the full Drupal page. Now it is rendering the title, but I am unable to get it working in Localhost in the XAMPP example, Windows XP. I suspect that some added module (Production) is fixing whatever the possible bug was. The code is exactly the same.

Comment: you mean when you access this page: mymodule/nojs/ctools_js?

Comment: exactly mymodule/nojs . %ctools_js is a placeholder for that or mymodule/ajax, so if you have Javascript active, it is the second URL which is chosen. Google bot will ever choose the first one, and if it has no title, will give a low SEO result for that page.